# SqlCommand select all columns with a certain value

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

I have a `SqlDataReader`, which needs to read certain values out of my database. The `SqlCommand` which selects these values looks like this:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Confronting_Value", valueConnection);
```

Each entry in the database consists of "Attacker", "Defender" and "Value". All 3 contain integer values.

For example

```
Attacker: "665", Defender: "443", Value: "3".
```

There may be multiple entries where the "Attacker" has the value "665".

Now, `SELECT WHERE Attacker = 665` would be simple, but I have a variable `Black.ID`. I want to select all entries where the Attacker has the same value as Black.ID. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly - but just adding a **parameter** to the query might work:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * 
                                        FROM dbo.Confronting_Value 
                                        WHERE Attacker = @Value", valueConnection);

// add parameter and set its value to "Black.ID"
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Black.ID;
```

and then from here on, run the code you already have. This will select all rows where `Attacker` has the same value as your `Black.ID` value.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, what is Black.ID? A variable in your code? A column of another table in the database?
In the first case add a Where clause to your command like this:

"SELECT * from dbo.Confronting_Value WHERE Attacker=" + Black.ID

or better

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Confronting_Value WHERE Attacker = @param1", valueConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Int);
myCommand.Parameters["@param1"].Value = Black.ID;
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: No. Do **not** use string concatenation. This kind of concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Always use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: Neather select *, it's a horrible bad practice.

Comment: Right Soner Gönul, improved my answer.

Comment: Yes, Parameters is what I was searching for. Thank you :)